# OBIEE count doesnt take into account applied filters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, aggregate, obiee

I am using OBIEE and recently I had to create simple analysis that takes following columns:

```
Day
Department
Count of sold items
```

All of them are attribute columns.

Filters are

```
Day = current day
Department = dep 01
```

However in results I see count of sold items not for current day but all time.

I tried to create logical column that counts in `OTHER` dimension and sums in `TIME` dimension with level day. But it shows the same number.

What can be the reason and how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I got desired result by adding `item_id` that was being counted in criteria and then hiding it in column properties. Then I excluded it in view properties which resulted in correct data. But is this always necessary action to do?

Comment: Is "Count of sold ítems" defined in the rpd?

Comment: @VictorHDC, originially, it is not defined in rpd. Since every item has its own unique id, I used Count("subject Area"."Item_id") in column formula. Even when I defined that in rpd with aggregation on time dimension and level to day, it showed wrong numbers

Comment: Can you please include a picture of your physical diagram?  are there 3 dimensions (department, Product, Time) and a Sales fact table?

Answer (score 1):

Get the physical query executed by OBIEE to compare your different versions:

1. Edit your analysis, go to "advanced" tab and copy the SQL Issued.
2. Go to "administration" and click on "issue SQL"
3. Copy the issued SQL from step 1 and add this line at the top:

   SET VARIABLE OBIS_REFRESH_CACHE=1,LOGLEVEL=2;
4. Click Issue SQL
5. In the administration menu, click "manage sessions" and sort by creation time desdending
6. Look for the record that includes your SQL in the statement and click "view log"
7. The log should include the physical query because it was executed with loglevel 2, look for the text "Sending query to database named"
8. Compare this physical query with the one you get by including a hidden item_id

You can also try defining the metric in the rpd without setting the aggregation level, just use count distinct on item id and leave all levels on default and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for reply @VictorHDC, I did what you said, the only difference in logs is that the one with hidden item_id adds item_id in group by and order by clause. Others are same

Comment: how is your metric defined in the rpd? have you tried count distinct on item id?

Comment: There is no column or attribute in database table that has count value of items, so I duplicated item_id column in rpd and then used sum aggreagtion with no result. I tried count distinct too but when I did that the analysis that  took 3 seconds to execute  started taking too long time like an hour. So I didnt use it

Comment: What are the columns on your sales fact table?  number of ítems sold should be a measure. a simple sales fact table would look like: AMMOUNT, QUANTITY, FK_ITEM, FK_TIME,FK_DEPARTMENT

Comment: There is no physical column 'Number of items sold' in table, I duplicated item_id in business layer and applied count aggregation on it, then renamed to "number of items sold".